# want to remove the extra space from the values while searching in the django admin

Tags: python, django, pandas, string, list

I have a list and as the text is too long i have applied the line breaks in it using the code as below: and also showing an example for the text **TESTTRACK00000000000**
**000000008**

```
def track(self, obj):
    if obj.tracking_no:
        line_length = 20 # used to break the text when it reaches 20 characters
        lines = [obj.tracking_no[i:i+line_length] + '\n' for i in range(0, len(obj.tracking_no), line_length)]  
        return ''.join(lines)
    return obj.tracking_no
```

but when copying the text for applying search in it  there is a space coming in between like **TESTTRACK00000000000** **000000008**

when copying the text for searching i want it as **TESTTRACK00000000000000000008** . need to remove the extra space in it.
I tried using **strip()** but its not working

Answer (score 1):

strip() only remove leading and tailing line breaks.

Yo need to use something like this to remove all line breaks:

```
def func(value):
    return ''.join(value.splitlines())
```

Also, to be sure that you don't keep any blank spaces you could do a replace to the string.

```
new_string = string.replace(" ", "")
```

Comment: actually i want to remove the white space of the above image inserted...and i need the line breaks as such. but when copying that entire text it shouldnot have a space in between them

Comment: Can any modifications be made in the above function i have stated

Comment: actually the the tracking number eg: TESTTRACK00000000000000000008  became to long i have line breaked when the length of character becomes 20 to next line. i need to display the tracking number as such with line breaks. But issue occures when copying that text for searching because when copying it the tracking number is having a space in between TESTTRACK00000000000 000000008

Comment: You can do something like this before return:
new_lines = []
for line in lines: 
    new_lines.append(line.replace(" ", "")
return new_lines

Comment: sorry (new_lines = [] for line in lines: new_lines.append(line.replace(" ", "") return new_lines)  this didnt worked for me